# Why does the limit of $F_X$ from the left equal $P (X < x)$?

Tags: probability-theory

I am trying the understand the definition of the cumulative distribution function:

> We use $F_X(x^-)$ to denote the limit of $F_X$ from the left $ lim_{ 0 < \Delta \rightarrow 0} F_X(x - \Delta )$ and $F_X(x^+) $ the limit from the right $ lim_{0<\Delta \rightarrow 0} F_X (x + \Delta )$. Note that $F_X (x^-) = P (X < x)$.

Why do we have $F_X (x^-) = P (X < x)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By [properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_%28mathematics%29#Measures_of_infinite_unions_of_measurable_sets) of probability measures we have:
$$
\begin{align}
P(X<x)&=P_X((-\infty,x))=P_X\Big(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \big(-\infty,x-\tfrac1n\big]\Big)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}P_X\Big(\big(-\infty,x-\tfrac1n\big]\Big)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty} F_X(x-\tfrac1n)=F_X(x^-).
\end{align}
$$
Here $P_X=P\circ X^{-1}$ is the distribution of $X$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a definition but a consequence of the fact that, the function $F_X$ being nondecreasing, $F_X(x^-)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}F_X(x-n^{-1})$ and of the identity
$$
\bigcup_{n\geqslant1}\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)\leqslant x-n^{-1}\}=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)\lt x\}.
$$